# The system cannot find the path specified error Vs Code-Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, visual-c#-express-2010

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKHNg.png)Hi I am working with Unity and Vs code and I tried to debug my code and I got "The system cannot find the path specified." error. My path is "c:\Users\UMUT\Desktop\Projects\Endless2\Assets\Last. I don't have any space in my path but in the beginning c letter of C drive  is small but it should be bigger letter (C).İs it related to that or are there any other reasons for this  error?
İf it is related to smalll "c" letter how can I fix that?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Last : MonoBehaviour
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Hi")
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
}
```

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive. So c: or C: won’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your path in this way,

"C:\Users\UMUT\Desktop\Projects\Endless2\Assets\Last"

if not resolved then please share screenshot of your code.

Comment: How can I write it like that I tried to debug but it makes C smaller.

Answer (score 0):

this is not your code error,
this is your project issue. Try to save all code or make another project and copy this code again to a new project with a different name and try to run. This will solve your problem hope so.

Comment: @Zafer Habib I am still getting same error. But thanks for help. If you have any other idea please share.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting Visual Studio Code's settings to default was able to fix it for me.